# Animation showing on emulator but on real device

Tags: android, android-emulator, dialog, android-animation, android-alertdialog

I was trying to show below sample dialog. It was working perfeclty on emulator but when I checked it on my device it's not showing any kind of transaction. I also tried by setting high duration value.

```
public class AnimActivity extends Activity{

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.test);
    Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setMessage("This will end the activity");
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setPositiveButton("I agree", new OkOnClickListener());
    builder.setNegativeButton("No, no", new CancelOnClickListener());
    final AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.Animations_SmileWindow;

    Button btn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    dialog.show();
    }

    });
}

private final class CancelOnClickListener implements
DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Activity will continue",
Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}

private final class OkOnClickListener implements
DialogInterface.OnClickListener {
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
finish();
}
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure, but i think if this is working within emulator then this might be the the problem with your mobile display settings.

Goto Setting->Display->Animation -> select All Animation

Hope it will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try to load your animation xml from "anim" folder. If you don't have that folder in your res folder create it manually and put your animation xml in it. then load it with

```
 R.anim.Animations_SmileWindow;
```

This may not be the solution but worth trying.